# How to install wxHaskell?

Tags: windows, haskell, wxwidgets, cabal-install, wxhaskell

I have downloaded the latest Haskell Platform(8.0.1 version) for Windows 7, wxWidgets-3.0.2, set all the needed environment variables. I have successfully installed "wxdirect" using "cabal install", but when I try to install "wxc" it fails. Install logs:

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswud\..: getDirectoryContents: does not exist
(The system cannot find the path specified.)
cabal: Leaving directory '.'
```

Where do I need to get that "gcc_dll\mswud\" folder?

P.S Neither Abriline nor Achelanne works for me for some reason.

P.P.S I tried to install this library following Haskell-wiki instructions, but it didn't work complaining about a ton of dependencies.

***UPDATE***
I tried installing the wxHaskell using Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 with Abriline installer. It stopped on building wxc. Logs:

```
Building wxc
setup.exe: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
 1] Compiling Main             ( wxc-0.92.2.0\dist\setup\setup.hs,     wxc-0.92.2.0\dist\setup\Main.o )
Linking .\wxc-0.92.2.0\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
The bitness is correct
Configuring wxc-0.92.2.0...
Configuring wxc to build against wxWidgets 3.0.2
cabal: Leaving directory '.\wxc-0.92.2.0'
```

***UPDATE***
Extended logs with "cabal install wxc -v3":
http://rgho.st/7BJcHzJTF

Comment: Try following the instruction from here: https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell
. It seems you need a lower version of Haskell platform according to the instructions specified there.

Comment: @Sibi I tried that, didn't work tho. Now it says that it can't find a file while building wxc.

Comment: Can you update the question with exact error messages? That's how others can help you.

Comment: You'll need to use the `-v3` option when building to get a better error message.

Comment: @Eric How do I do that with cabal-install?

Comment: Could it be that I need an older version of cabal-install? My current version is 1.24.0.0

Comment: Run` cabal build -v3`. However, I just noticed the `Maybe.fromJust: Nothing`.  That's strange since you're getting a runtime error during the build.

Comment: I have installed some packages that are mentioned in extended log, but it still doesn't work. Why is cabal-install complaining about gcc?

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems that maybe `pkg-config` is missing. From the platform's built in msys2 run `pacman -S pkg-config` and install it, see if it works after that.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed it as follows.

- Download [wxInstall-Achelanne-64-0.1.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhaskell/files/wxInstall/), unzip, and set this folder as the current directory in a terminal
- Type

`Set WXWIN=%CD%\wxWidgets
Set WXCFG=gcc_dll\mswu
Set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
cabal unpack wxdirect
cabal install ./wxdirect-xxx`

(where `xxx` is e.g. `0.92.3`).

- Find the file `wxdirect.exe` and put it in the current directory.
- Rename the file `wxWdigets/include/wx/setup_redirect.h` to `wxWdigets/include/wx/setup.h`
- Type

`cabal unpack wxc
    cabal install ./wxc-xxx`

- Find the file `wxc.dll` and put it in the `DLLs` folder.
- Put the folders `DLLs` and `wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll` in your search path.
- Now you can install `wxcore` and `wx`.